# What is meant by a 'strong' reference to an object, and why should we store the reference to OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener in an object's data?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, listener, android-preferences, android-sharedpreferences

From [this guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html) on Preferences,

> Caution: When you call registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(), the
>   preference manager does not currently store a **strong** reference to
>   the listener. You must store a **strong** reference to the listener,
>   or it will be susceptible to garbage collection.
>
> We recommend you keep a reference to the listener in the instance data
>   of an object that will exist as long as you need the listener.

1. **What do they mean by a *strong* reference here, as opposed to (just a) a reference?**
2. They are *recommending* to keep the reference in the the instance
   data of an object. This means that there are other ways of keeping
   the reference (in *static* variables?). So the question is that
   **why are they recommending to keep the reference in *instance data* of an object?**

Answer (score 4):

Simply put - 
[WeakReference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ref/WeakReference.html) is a java concept/class. Objects which are only referenced using weak reference get garbage collected in a GC pass.

On the other hand, Strong reference/the references that you use all the time( eg Integer a = 20;) doesn't let GC collect/free up objects.

So in your case, 
Let's say you register a OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener with the preference manager, the preference manager will store it as a non-strong reference (probably a weak reference).

```
prefs.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(
  //anonymous object, you don't hold the reference to the listener you create - this is susceptible to get garbage collected
  new SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener() {
  public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences prefs, String key) {
    // listener implementation
  }
});
```

This means that whenever the GC strikes, the listener object will get collected, as there is no strong reference anywhere to the listener object.As a result, the preference manager will lose the **weak** reference it holds to the listener you registered and you won't get any preference change callbacks thereafter.

BUT - if you store a STRONG reference to the listener yourself, somewhere in your code, it will make the GC skip collection/free-ing up of your listener object, as there is at least one strong reference to that object. This will let you keep receiving those callbacks from the preference manager.

```
public class ABC extends Activity{
    SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener listener; // this object will last until the enclosing activity is destroyed.

...onCreate(Bundle b){
    prefs.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(
      // Create a **strong** reference to the listener
      listener = new SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener() {
      public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences prefs, String key) {
        // listener implementation
      }
    });
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `Integer a = 20` rather than `int a`? I didn't think strong/weak references applied to primitives.

Answer (score 0):

The code in @Vinay Wadhwa's Answer got me through my problem with the docs' warning to store a "strong reference" to an `onSharedPreferenceChangeListener`.

Who knew that a "strong reference" was just a "normal" variable declaration.

So declare the listener like so:

`SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener listener;`.

And implement it.

I hope to help more in two ways:

(1) Give a slightly more complete example.

(2) "Unclutter" `onCreate` if listener is somewhat complex.

---

(1) Slightly more complete example:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
  SharedPreferences                 sp;
  OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener  listener; // will last until activity is destroyed

  @Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
  {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    sp = getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

    sp.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener
    (
      listener = new OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener() // strong reference
      {
        @Override public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences shpf, String key)
        {
          SharedPreferences.Editor editor = shpf.edit();
            switch(key) 
            {
              case PREF_SHORTEST_WORD:
                prefShortestWord = parseInt(shpf.getString(PREF_SHORTEST_WORD, "2"));break;
              case PREF_LONGEST_WORD:
                prefLongestWord = parseInt(shpf.getString(PREF_LONGEST_WORD, "15")); break;
              case PREF_MAX_MATCHES:
                prefMaxMatches = parseInt(shpf.getString(PREF_MAX_MATCHES, "50"));   break;
            } // switch
          editor.apply();
        } // onSharedPrefereeceChanged
      } // onSharedPreferenceChangeListener
    ); // registerJnSharedPreferenceChangeListener
    ...
  } // onCreate
...
} // MainActivity
```

---

But if the listener above becomes much more complex than the 3 cases shown above, `onCreate` may seem "cluttered" with code that could be better placed elsewhere.

(2) Uncluttered `onCreate`:

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity 
    {
      SharedPreferences                 sp;

      // don't declare here: OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener  listener;

      @Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
      {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        sp = getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

        sp.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(listener); // define listener later 

      ...
      } // onCreate
```

We definitely have an "uncluttered" `onCreate` above.

But where to define `listener`? As a private object at end of `MainActivity`:

```
... // end of MainActivity objects except one:

  private OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener listener =
    new OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener() // strong reference
    {
      @Override public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences shpf, String key)
      {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = shpf.edit();
        switch(key) // moment of truth
        {
          case PREF_SHORTEST_WORD:
            prefShortestWord = parseInt(shpf.getString(PREF_SHORTEST_WORD, "2")); break;
          case PREF_LONGEST_WORD:
            prefLongestWord = parseInt(shpf.getString(PREF_LONGEST_WORD, "15"));  break;
          case PREF_MAX_MATCHES:
            prefMaxMatches = parseInt(shpf.getString(PREF_MAX_MATCHES, "50"));    break;
        } // switch
        editor.apply();
      } // onSharedPrefereeceChanged
    }; // onSharedPreferenceChangeListener


  } // MainActivity
```

Make the listener as long as it takes. It's "out of the way".