# Removing unnecessary `val` qualifier breaks this class

Tags: java, android, kotlin, jvm, kotlin-flow

**Update: It's (almost) never a compiler bug, answered with explanation after coming back to it**

I have a class `OverlaySensorViewModel` that exposes a `Flow<Boolean>`. This `Flow` object comes from an object that it receives in a constructor:

```
class OverlaySensorViewModel(val repository: Repository) {
   val showTimer = repository.showTimer
}
```

Other classes then reference `showTimer` as `viewModel.showTimer`.

---

The `repository` parameter is not being used outside of initialization, so it technically doesn't need to be declared as a `val`.

And IntelliJ rightly points this out:

[image]

---

However... removing the `val` qualifier breaks the class: ***Subscriptions to `OverlaySensorViewModel.showTimer` will no longer work.***

In fact, to isolate the problem I tried moving all subscriptions to the class itself, and even in the init block they stop working:

```
 class OverlaySensorViewModel{
 //...
 init {
    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
        showTimer.collect{
            print("Updated $it") // Stops working if `val` is removed
        }
    }
}
```

Is this some sort of deep JVM initialization order quirk that I'm stumbling across? Or some Kotlin Flow inconsistency?

---

`Repository` has an implementation along the lines of:

```
class Repository{
    private val mutableShowTimer = MutableStateFlow(true)
    val showTimer = mutableShowTimer.asSharedFlow()
}
```

Could there be some sort of initialization order issue with the `.asSharedFlow()` call? Even so, I really don't understand how adding or removing `val` would change anything, especially with IntelliJ agreeing I didn't accidentally use it somewhere else

---

To deepen the mystery, I have another class that follows an almost identical pattern.

This class references `repository` outside of initialization, so as a test I captured the value of `repository` in a closure and removed `val`

```
class ConfigurationViewModel(repository : Repository) {
   val repositoryCaptor = { repostiory } // Needed so that val can be removed
   val showTimer = repostitory.showTimer
   // ...
   fun setShowTimer(value : Boolean){
      repositoryCaptor().setShowTimer(value)
  }
}
```

Everything continues to work. As I would expect, there's no meaningful difference between capturing the value at initialization or using it later on.

I'm really reluctant to just leave this be because it's extremely non-obvious that there'd be any difference.

I was thinking that it could be an issue with garbage collection, but holding onto a reference of `someObject.member` should prevent `someObject` from being garbage collected right? I'd also expect an NPE if anything, but subscriptions seem to just silently fail.

Both classes are created in a similar manner, `XXXViewModel(Repository())`, so I'd expect a similar failure in both cases too

---

**Edit:** For posterity these are the full class definitions, and a tag where it the issue exists

[OverlaySensorViewModel.kt (Having removed `val` at the linked line broke the class)](https://github.com/SelaliAdobor/Grupetto/blob/787361bac82e91d0a39c7b8cc546e14636f587cf/app/src/main/java/com/spop/poverlay/overlay/OverlaySensorViewModel.kt#L28)

[ConfigurationViewModel.kt (Works as expected despite identical usage)](https://github.com/SelaliAdobor/Grupetto/blob/787361bac82e91d0a39c7b8cc546e14636f587cf/app/src/main/java/com/spop/poverlay/ConfigurationViewModel.kt)

[ConfigurationRepository.kt (The repository in question)](https://github.com/SelaliAdobor/Grupetto/blob/787361bac82e91d0a39c7b8cc546e14636f587cf/app/src/main/java/com/spop/poverlay/ConfigurationRepository.kt)

Answer (score 0):

Thinking about this more, it makes sense, it was just very non-obvious what was happening because of the incorrect message from the IDE [1]

The gist of what I was doing is:

```
createViewModel() {
    val repository = new Repository()

    return new ViewModel(repository.showTimer) 
}
```

The root issue is: *As soon as the current scope is exited, nothing is referencing `repository`, and it's eligible for garbage collection.*

Normally this wouldn't be an issue, but in this case ***Repository was supposed to insert values into `showTimer`***.

`Repository` was listening to an event source and posting new values to `showTimer`. But once it's garbage collected it ceases to post to `showTimer`. So while `viewModel` has a reference to `showTimer`, *there's no one left to update it.*

---

Just to confirm that was exactly what was happening, I added a finalizer that logged the stack trace when Repository was collected, along the lines of:

```
   class Repository(){
       val stackTraceWhenCreated = GetStackTrace()

       fun finalize() { //Run when Repository is garbage collected
           logger.info("Repository finalized, was created at $stackTraceWhenCreated")
       }
   }
```

And sure enough, the logs show immediately after leaving `createViewModel`, the repository is garbage collected (heavily truncated logs:)

```
Repository was finalized, was created at:
  java.lang.Exception
   at Repository.Constructor
   at createViewModel()
```

---

So any change that that explicitly holds a reference to `repository` past the end of the function scope works... including adding `val`. That forces ViewModel to hold onto `repository` for its lifetime and allows `showTimer` to be updated.

I went with something a little more explicit and stored a reference to Repository in the calling class for createViewModel().

---

[1] Thinking about this *even more* I realized the reason why I've never run into this, despite it being such a common pattern, is a quirk of the event source being used

Normally registering a listener goes along the lines of

```
    val myListener = { this.updateValue() }
    eventSource.registerListener(myListener)

    //Some time later
    eventSource.unregisterListener(myListener)
```

Causing a reference to be held to `this` as long as the eventSource is subscribed to. But this specific `eventSource` explicitly mentions only holding *WeakReference* to its listeners (it's a long well known source of confusion: [What is meant by a 'strong' reference to an object, and why should we store the reference to OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener in an object's data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35935936/what-is-meant-by-a-strong-reference-to-an-object-and-why-should-we-store-the)).

I had accounted for this by storing the listener in a field, but since the only reference to said listener is a *WeakReference*, by extension the only reference to the entire class is a *WeakReference*

So I decided to fix it by having Repository hold a strong reference to the listener in a static variable, and adding an explicit "close" method to Repository.